# Installing/configuring telegram

Tags: applications

Telegram desktop seems to be a standalone app. I downloaded the 64bit Linux tgz and unzipped it in my downloads folder. Running the telegram binary launches the app instead of installing it. An icon for the app also appears in the notifications panel when it's running.

So my questions are...

Is it safe to run telegam from the home folder, or is there a preffered place for it?

How can I get it to permanently appear in the docker and/or application launcher?

I tried to get it to launch at boot by adding the binary's path to the startup apps, but it doesn't seem to work. That is, the icon doesn't appear in the notifications bar. Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you downloaded Telegram from Telegram's website, it should be safe to run from anywhere on your system, including the home folder.

When you open Telegram, an icon should appear in the dock. You can right click that icon and select "Keep In Dock" to keep it in the dock.

[image: Keep In Dock]

In order to have Telegram appear in Slingshot (the application launcher), you'll need to make a [desktop entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) and place it in either `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications`.

**Or you can install Telegram from a PPA and it will do all of this for you.**

To install Telegram from a PPA, open Terminal and run the following commands:

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram && sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install telegram`

After you install Telegram from the PPA, you can easily add it to your startup applications.

Comment: Ok, thanks. When I right click in the telegram icon in the docker bar, I only get a close option. But it's no big deal because I realised I had entered `/home/leke/Apps/Telegram` instead of `/home/leke/Apps/Telegram/Telegram` in the startup manager. So the app should open without user interaction now. I'll make the desktop entry for Slingshot. Perhaps that will fix the docker issue anyway.