# Telegram displayed two times

Tags: applications

first of all, happy new year. I'm a newbie of GNU/Linux world, Elementary OS is my first distro. 
I have a little problem with Telegram desktop: it works fine, but in the Applications Menu two instances of Telegram are displayed. I attach a screenshot to explain better:[image]

I've installed Telegram from PPA, as showed [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12096/installing-configuring-telegram). I've tried several times to remove/purge and then reinstall the package, with no result. Did it happen to anyone? Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Maybe check with the AppEditor app if you see a difference. You could also check whether it creates 2 .desktop files. It might be interesting to open an issue in app's issue queue ( https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Desktop ).

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. I've used AppEditor, and I think've solved: for one of the two I was able to delete entry. Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure :) Would be great if you could open an issue so that the Signal app developers are notified of the issue.

Comment: Actually it was Telegram desktop, not Signal